# ¿Asignar una variable dentro de un while con dos entreparentesis?

Tags: c, while

El programa consiste en un bucle que incluye una asignación con getchar(), la idea es que obtenga caracteres de entrada y los ponga como salida.

versión 1 (funcional):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar())!= EOF){
        putchar(c);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Terminal v1:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

versión 2 (no funcional):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int c;
    while (c = getchar()!= EOF){ //nótese que c = getchar() es diferente de ( c = getchar() )
        putchar(c);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

terminal v2:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La duda que tengo es ¿por qué ocurre esto? (obviando que da prioridad al entre paréntesis, es decir, ¿por que imprime caracteres extraños?)

Comment: los paréntesis se usan para separar las expresiones no es lo mismo hacer `2+4/2` que `(2+4)/2`

Comment: @Christian bien, pero por que ocurre (ademas de eso) para que  imprima caracteres extraños?

Comment: por que se cumple el `while` incorrectamente, ósea sigues enviando por consola cosas que no deberías. Lo cual también es considerado *basura*

Comment: @Christian datos basura te refieres?

Comment: Aparentemente al que inventó C se le ocurrió que la asignación sea una expresión en lugar de una instrucción normal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al hacer:
`(c=getchar()!=EOF)` primero hace la comparación y deacuerdo al resultado de esa conparación asigna a c ese valor.

```
getchar()!=EOF
```

Y despues asigna la variable c con esa comparación:

```
c=(getchar()!=EOF)
```

Y despues la funcion putchar lee ese numero como un caracter reeplezentado por la tabla ANSI.
Aqui te dejo un ejemplo en codigo de lo que acabo de decir:
[Ejemplo en tio.run](https://tio.run/##pY@xbsJAEER7f8WEKJItgUUdQpoIWoqkTLNar@1Tlj1ydw5CiK/KJ@TDnIPQUGernZH2zSzPOuZxvHfGOjSCp5ga5@v@uXCWsCVnZXUskOeseXFZdyGLtpysDC9IvvFQj89BYB5RCHNE15lrHRPeQvYPN9aaNEr9bpPqD7fvnQpKxhKdJO4plNXdEqvN@hp9k6kIEgdNlGNzYSWw3@4oELufb4PERzw0GT7lK/5U/O8@SBqCYb4oTuPYi@ZfXxPxBzZfElr1@/oX)

Al hacer esto:

```
(( c=getchar() )!=EOF)
```

Le dices al compilador que haga esto:

```
c=getchar();
(c!=EOF);
```